# получить в итоге только ключ : значение ? Перечисления бывают разными. Описание ниже

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, коллекции, arraylist

Вопрос уже был мною задан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491667/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82?newreg=f7b01c5ca58541269e5cbf347b3265fd) и @ipatev_nn дал мне подсказку, но не понимаю как улучшить..

У меня есть строка

```java
charAndValue = "[Type of document : A copy, the book, Document format : A4]"
```

Я пытаюсь решить свою проблему сплитом:

```
 String charAndValue = "[Type of document : A copy, the book, Document format : A4]"
 List<String> listVal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(charAndValue.split(", (?=[A-Z])")));
```

После сплита у меня лист с размером 2, как мне и нужно:

```
"Type of document : A copy, the book"

"Document format : A4"
```

Но есть вариант, когда приходит строка, например:

```
 String charAndValue = "[Регион оказания услуг : Москва, Московская область]"
```

И получается лист с размером два:

```
"Регион оказания услуг : Москва" 

"Московская область"
```

Comment: Во-первых, после `split` у вас останутся открывающая и закрывающая скобки: `"[Type of document : A copy, the book", "Document format : A4]"`.  Во-вторых, вам придётся улучшить формат данных: либо использовать особый разделитель для пар "ключ-значение", который не может использоваться внутри значений (например `; ` или другой символ), либо заключать в кавычки целую пару или по отдельности ключ и значение.  Иначе как вы будете обрабатывать случай, когда придут к примеру два региона: `[Регион 1: Город1, Область 1, Регион 2: Область 2]`?

Comment: @Nowhere Man спасибо за замечание, все учтено

Comment: Зачем вам две учётных записи? Просто отредактируйте свой [изначальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1491667/182013).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, тут немного другой случай, когда разделитель `, (?=\p{Lu})` уже работать не будет, т.к. значение тоже может содержать слово с большой буквы после запятой.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, отвечаю на вопрос про две учетные записи. Прошлый вопрос я задал из уз Гость и потерял доступ к ней и к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно дополнить условие разбиения: `", (?=\\p{Lu}[^:]+:)"`, тогда может отработать:

```java
String charAndValue = "[Type of document : A copy, the book, Document format : A4, Регион оказания услуг : Москва, Московская область, Российская Федерация]";
List<String> listVal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(charAndValue.split(", (?=\\p{Lu}[^:]+:)")));
listVal.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
[Type of document : A copy, the book
Document format : A4
Регион оказания услуг : Москва, Московская область, Российская Федерация]
```